# "Maximum common divisor" for entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I have found this exercise.

Let $f, g$ be entire functions.

a) Show that there exists entire $f_{1}, g_{1}$ and $h$ such that $f=hf_{1}$, $g = hg_{1}$ and $f_{1}$ and $g_{1}$ have no common zeros.

b) For $f$, $g$, and $h$ as above, show that there exists entire functions $A$ and $B$ such that $Af+Bg = h$.

Any idea ? How to manage the case ord($f$) = $\infty$ and ord($g$) = $\infty$ ?

Comment: The idea is that you first write down your own ideas, what you have done and so on.

Comment: I would try to find a function that has zeros wherever both $f_1$ and $g_1$ have zeros.

Comment: @WLOG: Use the Weierstrass factorization theorem.

Comment: @TooOldForMath: ok for the first point, but for the second ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1):** $f_1,g_1,h$ can be constructed by the Weierstrass factorization theorem.

**(2):** By (1) it suffices to find $a,b$ in the case that $f,g$ do not share any zeros (then $h=1$). Let $Z$ be the zero set of $f$.

Weierstrass/Mittag-Leffler's theorem(s) allow us to construct entire functions which take any given values in $\mathbb{C}$ (not only $0$) with any given multiplicities (*) on any discrete set in $\mathbb{C}$.

Let us denote by $\mathrm{ord}_z f$ the order of a zero of $f$ at $z$.

Therefore there exists an entire function $b$ such that $\mathrm{ord}_z (1-bg)\ge \mathrm{ord}_z f$ for all $z\in Z$.

By construction, the function $a:=\frac{1-bg}{f}$ is entire. It follows that

$$af+bg=1$$

*Note:*

(*) The multiplicity $k$ of $f$ at $z_0$ taking the value $w=f(z_0)$ can be defined using the Taylor development of $f$ at $z_0$:
$$f(z)-w=a_k (z-z_0)^k + O((z-z_0)^{k+1})$$
where $a_k\not=0$.

Comment: How can you say that there exists an entire function $b$ such that $\mathrm{ord}_z (1-bg)\ge \mathrm{ord}_z f$ for all $z\in Z$ ?

Comment: See Thm. 15.15 from Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*.

Comment: ok I have solved