# Write an entire function in terms of 2 entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis, problem-solving, entire-functions

This question was asked in complex analysis end term of previous year and I am trying to solve it to gain some experience.

I need help with following question:

> If f and g are entire functions with no common zeroes and if h is an entire function show that h can  be always written as h=fF+gG.with some entire functions F and G.

I am completely stumped on which theorem should I use to solve it as this question seems very hard for me and I am unable to get any intuition. Also, not much assignments  were given to us by course instructor due to Covid-19 and so it's a problem as I am often blank on how to approach some questions.

Entire functions are functions which are holomorohic on all of $\mathbb{C} $ .

Kindly shed some light on solution of this problem.

Comment: First [search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcomplex-analysis%5D+no+common+zeros) result on this site: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/654247/42969

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true [...], it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.  – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Comment: It's been years since prelims, but I imagine the idea is generalizing [Bezout's lemma](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Bezout%27s_Lemma) to entire functions. Obviously it doesn't literally apply, but glancing at the answer Martin R links, this seems like the right intuition, so I'll call this a hint.

Comment: Wierestrauss theorem